# Python frozen dataclass with an optional parameter but non-optional field type

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass such as this one:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyClass:
    my_field: str
    other_field: str
```

and I have a complicated function for computing a default value for `my_field` that depends on `other_field`:

```py
def get_default_value_for_my_field(other_field: str) -> str:
    ...  # lots of code
```

Is there a way to:

1. Call `get_default_value_for_my_field(other_field)` and initialize `my_field` from its result if no value for `my_field` is passed at initialization, otherwise initialize `my_field` from the passed value;
2. Keep `MyClass` frozen;
3. Convince `pytype` that `MyClass.my_field` has type `str` rather than `str | None`;
4. Convince `pytype` that `MyClass.__init__()` has a parameter `my_field: str | None = None`

using dataclasses, or am I better off switching to a plain class?

Answer (score 1):

Add a "named constructor" classmethod to your dataclass:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyClass:
    my_field: str
    other_field: str

    @classmethod
    def from_other(cls, other_field: str) -> MyClass:
        my_field = default_for_my_field(other_field)
        return cls(my_field, other_field)
```

You can then create `MyClass` instances as either

```
MyClass("my field", "other field")
```

or

```
MyClass.from_other("other field")
```

With this approach, `MyClass` stays a  "dumb" plain-old-data class. Special default value logic only kicks in at the user's request (by using the "named constructor").

Comment: Yes, this is my current approach. I suppose I should have included in my list of conditions "avoid creating additional constructors and just use `__init__()`".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that all those conditions are possible using daclasses. I used to have the same problem and found a package that can actually solve all the above very easily. The package is call [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/21.1.0/index.html), and if you use dataclasses you can see it does the same things but add some very cool features, without disturbing the class or similar as pydantic does.
It work the same as a dataclass and you probably will need to change very little of your code to move from dataclass to attrs, but is true it add a new dependency.

```py
from attrs import define

def get_default_value_for_my_field(other_field: str) -> str:
    ...  # lots of code


@define(frozen=True)
class MyClass:
    other_field: str
    my_field: str 

    def __init__(self, other_field: str, my_field: str|None):
        if not my_field:
            my_field = get_default_value_for_my_field(other_field)
        self.__attrs_init__(other_field=other_field, my_field=my_field)
```